# installing mongodb

Tags: apt, mongodb

i want to install mongodb on my machine (ubuntu linux 16.04) , so i follow [this instruction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) i do step 1 and step 2 but in step 3 when i enter command `sudo apt-get update` i get this error :

```
sudo apt-get update

Fetched 306 kB in 9s (33.9 kB/s)                                                                                          

Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-
org/3.4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch 
http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-
org/3.4/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old 
ones used instead.
```

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov when i open it with gedit it's a empty document

Comment: This mean for me step 2 was not successful. Enter by hand this text (one line) in to the file: `deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse`

Comment: @RomeoNinov now i have this line in the file but still get same error

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: yes , when i run `sudo gedit /etc/........................`  i can see the line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62777/discussion-between-mbehtemam-and-romeo-ninov).